# How avoid SVG from scaling as its container shrinks?

Tags: svg, scale

I want an SVG to *not* scale as its container shrinks. On scroll, my container shrinks its height (its width stays the same). That container contains an SVG that I want to *not* become scaled, but instead have its lower part become invisible/cut off.

I can do it if I (by CSS) use my SVG as a background, but I'd prefer to have the SVG inline in the HTML.

I have tried with various values for the SVG attribute `preserveAspectRatio`. I thought that the value `xMidYMin slice` would slice off the bottom part of my SVG (like I want), but it squashes its height instead.

My container is 245x80 px and on scroll is shrinked to 245x40 px.

My `svg` element has attribute `viewBox` set to `0 0 245 80` , and has no `width` or `height` explicitly defined.

Comment: remove the viewBox attribute altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice"` for the svg element.

Please observe that the svg element has a viewBox and also a width and a height. While the aspect ratio of the viewBox is 1:1 the aspect ratio from width and height is 2:1

> **xMidYMin** - Force uniform scaling.
> Align the midpoint X value of the element's viewBox with the midpoint X value of the viewport.
> Align the  of the element's viewBox with the smallest Y value of the viewport.

> **slice** - Scale the graphic such that:
> the aspect ratio is preserved and
> the entire viewport is covered by the viewBox

Please read more about [preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio)

In the next demo use the slider to change the height of the svg element

```js
itr.addEventListener("input",()=>{svg.setAttribute("height",itr.value)})
```

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<p><input id="itr" type="range" min="10" max="200" value="100"/></p>
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200" height="100" id="svg">
  <defs>
    <path style="fill:gold; stroke:black; stroke-width: 8px;
    stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round;" id="smiley" d="M50,10 A40,40,1,1,1,50,90 A40,40,1,1,1,50,10 M30,40 Q36,35,42,40 M58,40 Q64,35,70,40 M30,60 Q50,75,70,60 Q50,75,30,60" />
  </defs>

  <use href="#smiley" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Danke! To make my svg become as high as its surrounding container, should the svg-element's height attribute be 100%?

Comment: In this case a simpler idea would be `.container{overflow-y: hidden;}` and ignore all of the above. The overflow will cut the svg.